# Custom AlertDialog ScrollView, too big in 2.3 missing ok button

Tags: android, scrollview, android-alertdialog, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have to show a help info, instructions of how to use the program, i've chosen the AlertDialog using a custom XML with an ScrollView.
I tested in tablet, xperia neo and 2 virtual devices. In 3 of them goes good, but in the 2.3 with small screen,the dialog is too big and has a bug in the visualization that makes it hard to close. Any idea why?
Here is my code:
XML for the ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:textSize="10sp">
    </TextView>
</ScrollView>`
```

And for my code for calling it:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.msg_help)
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_scrollable,null))
           .setTitle(R.string.help_title)
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do things
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    alert.show();
```

Here is how it looks: http://postimg.org/image/wvg61x0qv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AlertDialog` makes its content scrollable automatically if it wouldn't fit on the screen. Instead of inflating your custom XML layout, simply just set the text to the dialog with <strike>`builder.setText()`</strike>`builder.setMessage()`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.msg_help)
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setTitle(R.string.help_title)
       .setMessage(R.string.help)
       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //do things
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Notice that I also removed the line with `alert.getWindow().setLayout()` because I think it's useless.

Comment: Glad it helped you even though I suggested to use an unexisting method. :) Thanks for the correction. I also corrected it in the text on top.